# How to host ASP.NET MVC website on Hostgator

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wordpress, web-hosting

I have created website with ASP.NET MVC and I need to host it in Hostgator.  I search on google and youtube for directions about that but I didnt find anything, just host wordpress, wordpress and wordpress, nothing for ASP.NET MVC applications.

This looks very unusual because I read many articles that evaluate Hostgator as one of best ASP.NET hosting service.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: download publish profile, right click your project -> publish -> select the profile -> hit ok, done

Comment: Have you checked that hosting plan is for windows or Linux?

Comment: I checked for windows

Comment: @Steve Do I have to change anything in configuration of ASP in hostgator

Comment: @I.Beqiri depends. If you are using shared hosting then download the file I mentioned is all you need and all you can do. Everything else happens in your web.config. If you use VPS or Dedicated server then that's a completely different story

Comment: where do you download publish profile from?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because your host server is linux not a windows,so that you do not have an access to asp.net

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).